# Difference between Exports, Indirect Exports, Requires and Indirect Requires in Java9?

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system, access-specifier

I was going through the API docs for [`jdk.accessibility`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/jdk.accessibility-summary.html) and noticed that it lists all these separately.

1. The modules with scope `requires`  in one module are all consuming module's *Indirect Requires*?
2. The `module-info.java` for the module is as follows:

   ```
   module jdk.accessibility {
       requires transitive java.desktop;

       exports com.sun.java.accessibility.util;
   }
   ```

   and for `java.desktop` is something like(trying to include varying  -

   ```
   module java.desktop {
       ...
       requires java.prefs;
       ...
       requires transitive java.xml;
       exports java.applet;
       ...
       exports sun.awt to
           javafx.swing,
           jdk.accessibility,
           oracle.desktop;
       opens javax.swing.plaf.basic to jdk.jconsole;
       ...
       uses javax.sound.sampled.spi.MixerProvider;
       ...
       provides javax.sound.sampled.spi.MixerProvider with
           com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDeviceProvider,
           com.sun.media.sound.PortMixerProvider;
   ```

   But then the doc for `jdk.accessibility` does not mention `sun.awt` as either Requires or Indirect Requires or Indirect Exports. What's the reason of inconsistency here?

Looking for examples of the difference between these that can help understand what is happening in **(2)** and what shall be followed as a practice for us to adapt to module structure using Java9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that in:

```
module java.desktop {
    ...
    ...
    exports sun.awt to
        javafx.swing,
        jdk.accessibility,
        oracle.desktop;
}
```

that `sun.awt` is a package, not a module name. ([Here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_java_9/blob/master/egg_04_Open_Module/src/net.codetojoy.db/module-info.java) is another example.) So it makes sense that `sun.awt` would not be mentioned in the doc, as `java.desktop` is already cited.

**Edit:** Also, note that for clients of the `jdk.accessibility` module, the `sun.awt` package is not accessible. That is, it is exported by `java.desktop` *for use by* `jdk.accessibility` but does not become part of its API. I have confirmed ([example here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_java_9/tree/master/egg_33_stack_overflow_45862518)) that this is true even though `jdk.accessibility` requires `java.desktop` as `transitive`.

Comment: Not mentioned as a package either is what I meant. http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/jdk.accessibility-summary.html

Comment: I have updated the answer with info as I understand the question. If a module A "exports sun.awt to B" then clients of B cannot see "sun.awt", even if B does "requires transitive" on A.